# Movie booking: How to let every show have its own set of seats?

Tags: sql, eclipse, mysql-workbench

I have made a movie booking database in mysql workbench (6.2). This database is then connected to eclipse where I in java have programmed a GUI for the movie booking system.

Everything works well with the GUI/database but there is one logical problem:
If a reservation is made for a show, naturally, the number of seats left in that theater where that show is to be played, will be reduced by 1 for every reservation. But if there is a show that's on a **different** date but on the **same** theater then this theaters seats is also reduced by 1 which is wrong.

E.g. a show on *Monday* should have its own set of seats and one on *Tuesday* should have its own. A solution could be to create a new column 'nbrseats' in 'shows' but I want it to get its seats from Theaters if that's possible.

Database

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
drop table if exists Users;
drop table if exists Theaters;
drop table if exists Movies;
drop table if exists reservations;
drop table if exists Shows;

create table Theaters ( 
    theatername char(11) not null,
    NbrSeats char(20) not null,
    primary key (theatername)
)engine innoDB;

create table Movies ( 
    moviename char(30) not null,
    primary key (moviename)
)engine innoDB;

create table Shows (   
    movieDate DATE not null,  
    theatername char(11) not null,  
    moviename char(30) not null,
    id integer auto_increment,

    foreign key (theatername) references Theaters(theatername),  
    foreign key (moviename) references Movies(moviename),
    primary key (id) 
)engine innoDB;

create table Users ( 
    username char(20) not null,
    fullname char(30) not null,
    phonenbr char(10) not null,
    address varchar(20) not null,

    primary key (username)
) engine innoDB;


create table reservations (
    resNbr integer auto_increment,
    username char(20) not null,
    showId int(30) not null,

    foreign key(showid) references Shows(id),
    foreign key (username) references Users(username),
    primary key (resNbr)
)engine innoDB;

-- insert data into the tables
insert into Users values
('Temp1','Name Name', '0701231231', 'Street1');

insert into Movies values
('Star Wars'),
('Dallas'),
('Falcon Crest');

insert into Theaters values
('Filmstaden', '100'),
('SF', '129'),
('Royal', '120');

insert into Shows values
('20151203','Royal', 'Falcon Crest', null),
('20151003','SF', 'Dallas', null),
('20150803','Filmstaden', 'Star Wars', null);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need a table for reservations that will join Theaters and Shows. Each reservation will carry it's own information, like number of seats, cost, etc. So you don't have to decrement number of seats at all.

Comment: You could e.g. dynamically compute it by looking at the theatre for the show and getting the number of seats, then summing all of the rows in reservations for that show and subtracting the number of seats booked from the number originally available.

Comment: Is it really just number of seats you are interested in? Usually a booking refers to certain seats, not only a number of seats.

Comment: @Rup Thanks! My database was correct, it was just a matter of querying from eclipse. Here is an example query: select nbrseats - (select count(showId) from reservations where showId = (select id from shows where id = 2)) from theaters
where theatername = (select theatername from shows where id = 2);                                 Thorsten and Bulat thanks for input!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new column to store the number of booked seats in the reservations table. Then you can write a query to calculate the number of free seats based on the reservations made and the seats available in this theater.

Example to get free seats of showid 1, with two reservations of 5 and 2 seats:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
drop table if exists Users;
drop table if exists Theaters;
drop table if exists Movies;
drop table if exists reservations;
drop table if exists Shows;

create table Theaters ( 
    theatername char(11) not null,
    NbrSeats char(20) not null,
    primary key (theatername)
)engine innoDB;

create table Movies ( 
    moviename char(30) not null,
    primary key (moviename)
)engine innoDB;

create table Shows (   
    movieDate DATE not null,  
    theatername char(11) not null,  
    moviename char(30) not null,
    id integer auto_increment,

    foreign key (theatername) references Theaters(theatername),  
    foreign key (moviename) references Movies(moviename),
    primary key (id) 
)engine innoDB;

create table Users ( 
    username char(20) not null,
    fullname char(30) not null,
    phonenbr char(10) not null,
    address varchar(20) not null,

    primary key (username)
) engine innoDB;


create table reservations (
    resNbr integer auto_increment,
    username char(20) not null,
    showId int(30) not null,
    seats int not null,

    foreign key(showid) references Shows(id),
    foreign key (username) references Users(username),
    primary key (resNbr)
)engine innoDB;

-- insert data into the tables
insert into Users values
('Temp1','Name Name', '0701231231', 'Street1');

insert into Movies values
('Star Wars'),
('Dallas'),
('Falcon Crest');

insert into Theaters values
('Filmstaden', '100'),
('SF', '129'),
('Royal', '120');

insert into Shows values
('20151203','Royal', 'Falcon Crest', null),
('20151003','SF', 'Dallas', null),
('20150803','Filmstaden', 'Star Wars', null);

insert into reservations values
(null,'Temp1', 1, 5),
(null,'Temp1', 1, 2),
(null,'Temp1', 2, 3);


select
  Shows.id,
  Shows.theatername,
  Theaters.NbrSeats,
  sum(reservations.seats),
  Theaters.NbrSeats-sum(reservations.seats) freeseats
from Shows
  left join Theaters
  on Shows.theatername = Theaters.theatername
  left join reservations
  on Shows.id = reservations.showId
where Shows.id = 1
group by
  Shows.id,
  Shows.theatername,
  Theaters.NbrSeats
```

Comment: Neat, particularly the query, although I think his schema assumes that it's one seat per reservation so maybe that's a requirement for this exercise. IMO shows should join to movies and theatres by a numeric ID though not by string, but that's fairly moot for a small number of records, and the reservation table which won't have a small number does join by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Database is correct, it was a matter of querying

here is an (somewhat primitive) example query for id = 2:

```
select nbrseats - (select count(showId) from reservations 
where showId = (select id from shows where id = 2)) from theaters
where theatername = (select theatername from shows where id = 2);
```

Comment: Neat. Note that `(select id from shows where id = 2)` is redundant, and it'd feel more natural to me to make this a query against shows than against theatres (e.g. like Josh's, although that supports more than one seat reserved per reservation record) or shows then joined to theatres, but if you only need a single number result that's irrelevant.